# Displaying arbitrary HTML (or webgl) inside a Drupal frame (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to have a page inside my drupal site that would show a webGL Canvas but it seems that Drupal tries to shield its user from doing any direct HTML hacking on a page.

How would one embed a webGL Canvas (or any other arbitrary html for that matter) inside a Drupal page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you may also not want to create your HTML page containing a WebGL canvas as *content* managed by Drupal. Instead, you can [create a custom module](https://drupal.org/node/1074360) providing a single page with your canvas and the additional JavaScript and CSS files.

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  return array(
    'path/to/canvas' => array(
      'title' => 'Awesome WebGL application', 
      'page callback' => 'MODULE_canvas_page', 
      'access callback' => TRUE, 
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ),
  );
}

function MODULE_canvas_page() {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/module.js');
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE') . '/module.css');
  return theme('webgl_canvas');
}

function MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'webgl_canvas' => array()
  );
}

function theme_webgl_canvas() {
  return '<canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480">Your browser doesn\'t appear to support the HTML5 <code>&lt;canvas&gt;</code> element.</canvas>';
}
```

The `MODULE_menu()` is an implementation of [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). It declares a page available at `path/to/cancvs` and handled by the `MODULE_canvas_page()` function. The handler function adds JavaScript and CSS files using the [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) and [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) which allow the files to be aggregated into single `.js`/`.css` files (if that feature is enabled for the site). It then return the markup for the WebGL canvas. The markup is produced by a theme hook function (`theme_webgl_canvas()`) declared in `MODULE_theme` which is an implementation of [`hook_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7). This allow the theme or other modules to change the markup.

Because a WebGL page/application would likely use a lot of custom JavaScript, you may also want to check the [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/756722) guide.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal uses input filters which can be setup to allow any html or limit the allowed html a user can input. You will need to configure and select a input filter that allows you to enter the html you want to display.

Other than that - Drupal won't do any limitations on the HTML allowed.